# Failure to add a visible label to ChartJSImage on doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to make a doughnut chart where each arc has a string of a particular format. There are limited options in ChartJSImage and I am wondering if it is even possible. To make it clearer, the first picture is what I am getting and the second picture is what I want.

1. What I am getting
   [image: What I am getting]
2. What I want
   [image: What I want]

The issue looks easy, but I feel like ChartJSImage is very limited and I can't find a solution to it. Here is my code that I tried

```js
const line_chart =  ChartJSImage().chart({
  "type": "doughnut",
  "data": { 
  labels: [
    'Carbs',
    'Protien',
    'Fats'
  ],
  options: {
  plugins: { 
    legend: { // i assumed that I had to put the legend key? still did not work.
      display: true,
      position: 'top',
      align: 'center'
    }
  }
},
datasets: [{
  label: 'Calorie Intake',
  data: [300, 50, 100], // I want to use each number in the array and then 'cal'
  backgroundColor: [
    'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
  ]
}],

}}) // Line chart
.backgroundColor('white')
.width(500) // 500px
.height(300); // 300px

line_chart.toFile('myimg.png')
```

If it is even possible to add labels to a doughnut using ChartJSImage, then please tell me how.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution would simply be to use the chartjs-plugin **chartjs-plugin-datalabels**, check [link /documentation of the plugin](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/).

Just install / or Download it ( [checkout the get started section](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#installation) )

In your code you then just need to load the plugin, and configure how you want the resulting chart to look like.

**Here a short Demo, matching the needed output:**
*(Comments in the code mark settings/configuration that has to be added)*

```js
let data = {
  labels: [
    'Carbs',
    'Protien',
    'Fats'
  ],
  datasets: [{
    data: [70, 30, 50],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
    ],
    
    // Configuring labels for the specific dataset
    datalabels: {
      anchor: 'center',
      backgroundColor: null,
      borderWidth: 0
    },
  }]
};

var options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data,
  
  // Adding the Plugin to the Chart
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: { display: false },
    cutout: 20,
    plugins: {
    
      // Configuring the plugin
      datalabels: {
        color: 'white',
        formatter: function (value, context) {
          return `${value} cal`;
        },
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        },
        padding: 6,
      }
    },
  },
}

const chart = document.getElementById('chart1')
new Chart(chart, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.2.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:500px;height:184px">
   <canvas id="chart1" width="500" height="184"></canvas>
<div>
```

**Code that should work:**
*(base of the [documentation](https://documentation.image-charts.com/chart.js/))*

```js
{
    type: 'doughnut',
    data:{
        labels: [
          'Carbs',
          'Protien',
          'Fats'
        ],
        datasets: [{
          data: [70, 30, 50],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
            'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
          ],
        }]
      },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      legend: { display: false },
      datalabels: ["70 cal", "30 cal", "50 cal"]
    },
  }
```

[image: Screenshot online viewer]]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to run it in Node.js and I want to use ChartJSImage and not Chart,.js

Comment: @IssacHoward Yes you should beable to use this also with node.js, just install the plugin as mentioned in the get started section `npm install chartjs-plugin-datalabels --save`. To be an the same side I will try it but it should work. (you mean this [node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js-image) or?)

Comment: yeah I mean that node package, and I can't use the DOM in my code.

Comment: I updated my answer, it seem some type of datalabel plugin is installed, nothing else needed, just generate teh config json like in the example, than the label should apear, tested locally and on the [online viewer](https://editor.image-charts.com/). I hope this helps.